# How does extended slicing in python works?

Tags: python, slice

The `slice` syntax is a handy way to refer to sub-parts of sequences – typically strings and lists. The slice `s[start:end]` is the elements beginning at start and extending up to but not including end.

E.g

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
print(letters[2:5])
```

This will give Output : `['c', 'd', 'e']`

But how does extended slicing work.

```
print(letters[2:4:5])
```

The above print statement will give `['c']` as output. I can't understand how?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the 3rd parameter is called "step"

```
(start:end:step)
```

When you say:

```
print(letters[2:4:5])
```

Basically you are saying, start at index 2, end at 4 and step 5 times.

For example:

```
print(letters[::2])
```

Returns `['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']`

Two things to note:

1) In your case, even if you said `print(letters[2:4:1000])` the output would still be 'c'

2) Default "step" value is 1.

Comment: SO has a duplicate flag to avoid repetitions. It is better to collect all answers under one question then to have them scattered all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

The slice will essentially work as a step value. Let us assume we have a list of numbers from 1-10. The additional slice will simply work like a "step" value. Here's an example:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(nums[0:10:2])
```

We step by 2 each time. Here is our output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

You get C as your output because You are calling the third index, and then slicing up to the 5th index (index 4 since indexes in Python are zero-based), but you are stepping by a value of 5. So you can't step by 5, because that goes past the index that your slice stops at (index 5, or index 4 in zero-based Python syntax). That is why your code only returns 'c'.

Comment: SO has a duplicate flag to avoid repetitions. It is better to collect all answers under one question then to have them scattered all over the place.